# Number of bags such that any amount required between Re 1 and Rs. 158 can be given by handing out a certain number of bags without opening them.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, proof-verification

Ashish is given Rs. 158 in one-rupee denominations. He has been asked to allocate them into a number of bags such that any amount required between Re 1 and Rs. 158 can be given by handing out a certain number of bags without opening them. What is the minimum number of bags required?

I have applied brute force method to get the number is eight.

79 , 40 , 20 , 10 , 5 , 2 , 1 , 1

But how to prove that eight is the least number of bags. I think there is a bigger , deeper concept behind it. Can anyone please explain me how it is the least number of bags and if there is any number theory concept behind it?

Comment: I did not get you. Can you please explain little bit more?@MorganRodgers

Comment: Cardinality of the power set? so for 3 it will $8$ and $n$ it is $2^n$  ..But how this is related  to my question? @MorganRodgers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have $n$ bags, then there are $2^n$ different combinations of bags that you can hand out (including handing out 0 bags). Some combinations of bags might total the same amount of money, so with $n$ bags, you can hand out **at most** $2^n$ different money amounts (including 0).

You need to be able to hand out any money amount between $1$ and $158$; this will be impossible to do with $n$ bags when $2^n < 159$.

Comment: Yea, That is my answer !

Answer (score 3):

Nice problem.  I don't think the answer is unique.  What about eight bags filled with these denominations?:

$\{1,2,4,8,16,32,64,31\}$

By considering the binary expansion of the number of rupees we want, the first seven bags allow any number between 1 and 127.  To get larger numbers (between 128 and 158), include 31 and the needed other bags to get there.

Comment: But this is not my answer ? Please go through my question .. I wanted to know why eight is the least number?@mjw

Comment: Okay.  I guess we can make an inductive argument.  Let's say we wanted Rs. 1 through 3.  We need two bags, right?  {1,2}.  To get Rs. 1 through 7, we can do it in three bags {1,2,4}.  There is no way to get Rs. 1---8 in three bags.  Similarly, to get Rs. 1---127, we need seven bags, and Rs. 128 cannot be done in seven.  Therefore, to get Rs. 1---128 (and also Rs 1---158 or Rs. 1---255) we need eight bags.  Because we want less than 255 as the maximum number, the solution is not unique.

Comment: Think of it this way.  If we have seven bags, each bag containing $2^k$ rupees, if we add one or more to a bag, we will miss a number between one and $2^k$.